# How to pass run time parameters accepted from user to a TestNG test case?

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

I have a swing frame which accepts some input from user, ex: username, password.

I want to pass that input to a TestNG test case or testng.xml.
I can't pass hardcoded parameters using `@Parameter`, `@DataProvider`.

Comment: So you want to pass the value of the username and the password in testng.xml or in command line?